# Escapar caracteres en elastic search

Tags: javascript, nodejs, nestjs, elasticsearch

Tengo un proyecto con nest e instale este paquete de elastic @elastic/elasticsearch , actualmente tengo este método que realiza una búsqueda de documentos indexados

```
   searchIndex(searchData) {
    const client = new Client({
      node: process.env.ELASTIC_URL.toString(),
      Connection: HttpConnection,
      auth: {
        username: process.env.ELASTIC_USER,
        password: process.env.ELASTIC_PASS,
      },
    });
    return client.search({
      index: searchData.indice,
      query: {
        wildcard: { nameWithoutExtension: `${searchData.data}*` },
      },
    });
  }
```

cómo puedo hacer que el api de elastic realice búsquedas con caracteres como @ - . ..., por ejemplo si hago una búsqueda con @domain me arroja todo lo que contenga domain, no tiene en cuenta la @, igual pasa cuando hago la búsqueda por ejemplo con -2023 arroja todo lo que tenga 2023 pero omite -